# Launching emacs from java with arguments... not working

Tags: java

I'm running under linux with the bash shell, and

I have some java code that is attempting to launch emacs using processbuilder... I need to luanch emacs with a spefic set of arguments to the tool...  instead it always reports error 1 and fails.

What's the best way to do this?

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class test5 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test with arguments
        
        // Doesn't work
        String command = "emacs -nw";
        
        // works
        //String command = "emacs";

        testShellCommand(command);
    }

    public static void testShellCommand(String command) {
        try {
            ProcessBuilder processBuilder;
            String osName = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
            if (osName.contains("win")) {
                processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/C", command);
            } else {
                processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("bash", "-c", command);
            }

            Process process = processBuilder.start();

            // Read the output of the command
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }

            int exitCode = process.waitFor();
            System.out.println("Command executed with exit code: " + exitCode);

            if (exitCode != 0) {
                System.err.println("Command execution failed with exit code: " + exitCode);
                System.exit(1);
            }
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            System.err.println("Error executing command: " + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my output

```bash
$ javac test5.java
$ java test5
Command executed with exit code: 1
Command execution failed with exit code: 1
<Should see emacs window open here...but don't>
```

Comment: I would add `processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);` and re-try - always worth the time checking the `errorStream` as well

Comment: Doesn't ProcessBuilder just take a collection of args - so "emacs -nw" needs to be broken into 2 strings:  "emacs" and "-nw" ?

Comment: @John3136 Because they're passing it the shell, that might change, as the shell may want the args in a single string, but it would need to be tested further

Comment: Why are you not happy with the command that *does* work? The other one is, afaik (I use vim, not emacs) confined to running it within the context of a terminal session. That's not really suitable for automation

Answer (score 1):

You should pass a `String[]` to invoke the command with arguments. Also, things are *much* simpler if you take advantage of `ProcessBuilder.inheritIO()`. Finally, you don't need to specify `bash` or `cmd`. Something like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] command = { "emacs", "-nw" };
    testShellCommand(command);
}

public static void testShellCommand(String[] command) {
    try {
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
        processBuilder.inheritIO();
        Process process = processBuilder.start();
        int exitCode = process.waitFor();
        System.out.println("Command executed with exit code: " + exitCode);

        if (exitCode != 0) {
            System.err.println("Command execution failed with exit code: " + exitCode);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        System.err.println("Error executing command: " + e.getMessage());
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```